# Sort array onClick and render the array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array full of objects that I fetched and I am trying to sort the array onClick of an arrow in React. I have a sort function that works perfect in javascript but I am new to React and can't figure out how to implement the function and render the list again.

I am getting errors messages of all sorts depending on what I try. Anything from cannot sort undefined to 'expecting onclick to be a function instead of an object like in this case.

```
 var LeaderBoard = React.createClass({

sortDescending: function(property) {
    return function (a,b) {
        return (a[property] > b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] < b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
    }
},

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        data: loading
    };
},

componentWillMount: function() {
  fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent', {
      method: 'get'
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      this.setState({
          data: data,
      });
  }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("error is ", error);
  });
},

render: function() {
  var information = [];
  for (var j=0; j<13; j++) {
      information.push(
          <div className="row" key={this.state.data.username}>
              <div className="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                  <h4>{j+1}</h4>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                  <h4>{this.state.data[j].username}</h4>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                  <h4>{this.state.data[j].recent}</h4>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                  <h4>{this.state.data[j].alltime}</h4>
              </div>
          </div>
      );
  }
  return (
    <div>
        <div id="Title" className="row">
            <h1>freeCodeCamp Leaderboard</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <h4>#</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                <h4>Camper Name
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
                <h4>Points in past 30 days
                    <img className="arrow" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-up-b-128.png" />
                    <img className="arrow" onClick = {this.state.data.sort(this.sortDescending("recent"))}
                         src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png" />
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                <h4>All time points</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>{information}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting onClick to tbe result of a function, not tbe function itself.

Replace

```
`<img className="arrow" onClick={this.state.data.sort(this.sortDescending("recent"))}              src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png" />`
```

With

`<img className="arrow" onClick = {() => this.state.data.sort(this.sortDescending("recent"))}                       src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png" />`

React onClick events cannot be anything but a function, for future reference. (Also, JS refers to Arrays sometimes as Objects, which explains the error you're getting)

Comment: Ok thanks that fixed the array error message but it still wasn't updating. After messing around, I realized if I just added setState it would update so the final on click looked this: onClick = {() => this.setState(this.state.data.sort(sortAscending("recent")))}